# JavaScript: Simple subtraction returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a problem,
my collision detection function sometimes sets entity position to NaN.
When I open console (on chrome) position of entity and collision are valid numbers but subtracting them from each other sometimes returns NaN.

```
updateCollision = function(entity,rect) {
var a = entity.x - rect.x; // a = NaN , entity.x = 3117.2646499953607 , rect.x = 3296.976967651385
var b = entity.y - rect.y; // b = NaN , entity.y = 3024.105915848102 , rect.y = 3144.4270586199345

if( isNaN(a) ) // isNaN(a) = true
{
    console.log("not again >:("); // but console doesn't log
}

//the code continues but its not important
```

screenshot of console:

[image: (screenshot of console)]

So I am really confused, and don't know what to do with this issue.

Comment: perhaps you call updateCollision badly - how about you console.log entity and rect and make sure the x/y properties of each are actually numbers

Comment: You should log something more useful, like the values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Please update the question to include a [mcve] of the problem. Your screenshot shows Chrome's dev tools and you highlighting things while code is paused, but notably **doesn't show what statement you're paused on** (which would be highlighted in blue). So while those variables may well have those values as of whatever statement that is, it's clearly not in that screenshot of code and not right at the start of that function where `a` and `b` are calculated, so we have no way of helping you figure out what's going on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cg6a3ppn/ - your updateCollision code works just fine with correct inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewriten the code one more time and I dont get the NaN values anymore

Fixed function:

```
updateCollision = function(entity,rect) {
var a = entity.x - rect.x;
var b = entity.y - rect.y;

var unrotatedCircleY = Math.sin((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*a + Math.cos((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*b +rect.y;
var unrotatedCircleX = Math.cos((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*a - Math.sin((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*b +rect.x;
var r = entity.collRad/2;

var closestX, closestY, aX, aY;


if (unrotatedCircleX < rect.x - rect.width/2 )
{
    closestX = rect.x - rect.width/2;
    aX = closestX;
}
else if (unrotatedCircleX  > rect.x + rect.width/2 )
{
    closestX = rect.x + rect.width/2;
    aX = closestX;
}
else
{
    closestX = unrotatedCircleX;
    aX=rect.x;
}

if (unrotatedCircleY < rect.y - rect.height/2 )
{
    closestY = rect.y - rect.height/2;
    aY = closestY;
}
else if (unrotatedCircleY > rect.y + rect.height/2 )
{
    closestY = rect.y + rect.height/2;
    aY = closestY;
}
else
{
    closestY = unrotatedCircleY;
    aY = rect.y;
}


var collision = false;

var distance = getDistance(unrotatedCircleX , unrotatedCircleY, closestX, closestY);
if (distance < r)
collision = true;
else
collision = false;

if( collision && entity.type == "bullet")
{
    entity.hp = 0;
}
else if(collision)
{
    if( entity.type == "bullet")
    {
        DeleteEntity(entity);
        return;
    }
    if( rect.collType == "solid" )
    {

        var positionAngle = Math.atan2( -closestY + unrotatedCircleY , -closestX + unrotatedCircleX );

        var y_vel = Math.sin((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*entity.x_vel + Math.cos((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*entity.y_vel;
        var x_vel = Math.cos((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*entity.x_vel - Math.sin((-rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*entity.y_vel;

        y_vel *= 0.9;
        x_vel *= 0.9;



        unrotatedCircleX = closestX + Math.cos(positionAngle)*(r);
        unrotatedCircleY = closestY + Math.sin(positionAngle)*(r);

        a = unrotatedCircleX - rect.x;
        b = unrotatedCircleY - rect.y;

        entity.y = Math.sin((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*a + Math.cos((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*b + rect.y;
        entity.x = Math.cos((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*a - Math.sin((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*b + rect.x;

        entity.y_vel = Math.sin((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*x_vel + Math.cos((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*y_vel;
        entity.x_vel = Math.cos((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*x_vel - Math.sin((rect.angle)/180*Math.PI)*y_vel;
    }
    if( rect.collType == "trigger" )
    {
        if( level["commandList"][rect.data].command == "tp" )
        {
            entity.x = level["commandList"][rect.data].x;
            entity.y = level["commandList"][rect.data].y;
        }
        if( level["commandList"][rect.data].command == "loadLevel" )
        {
            levelToLoad = level["commandList"][rect.data].x;
        }
    }
}
```

But thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -2):

I need to see more of your code, to see what is actually wrong, but surely NaN is a result of math operations on an `undefined` type, so take a good look if something is `undefined`

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't see your screenshot but, `undefined` can be an issue, when you pass an object to a function, if you assign a value (undefined) to one of its property the whole objects would be affected (because somehow it's by reference), I experience this issue when I was working with turbulenz game engine collision detection too, and that was some kina `undefined`. so change your function to function(entity_x, entity_y, rect_x, rect_y), see if it works.